# Swagger plugin issue on GCP - Strapi

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, swagger, strapi

I'm using the [Swagger plugin for Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/api-documentation-plugin). It works fine on localhost, but when I deploy to App Engine it fails.

When accessing the /documentation page from the Strapi admin panel on a GCP App Engine (Standard) instance, I am seeing the below errors in GCP logs and Page not found with a 404 error.

`error Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/workspace/extensions/documentation/public/index.html'`

The documentation plugin was installed in my LOCAL development environment and docs compiled before deploying to GCP App Engine. Locally it works fine.

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

1. launch your Strapi project
2. active the Swagger documentation plugin
3. request the documentation locally (it will work)
4. upload the Strapi project to Google App Engine (gcloud command or whatever)
5. visit the documentation (https://YourGoogleProject.appspot.com/documentation/v1.0.0)

**System**

- Node.js version: v14.17.6
- NPM version: 8.1.2
- Strapi version: v3.6.8
- Database: MongoDB